# Tikz: connecting two vectors from the focus of an ellipse to the edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw 2 vectors from the focus to the an arbitrary point on the ellipse (not necessarily arbitrary but if I can see how to do that, I can pick my locations afterwards).

The solid circle is the focus and the other is the empty focus which I am not considering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate around = {-20:(0, 0)}]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1.5}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
      \draw (-3, 0) -- (3, 0);
      \filldraw[white] (-\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %empty focus
      \draw (-\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %empty focus
      \filldraw[black] (\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %focus
      \draw plot[domain = -99:99] ({\a * cos(\x)}, {\b * sin(\x)});
      \draw plot[domain = -99:99] ({-\a * cos(\x)}, {\b * sin(\x)});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would draw the ellipse using the `ellipse` command, instead of the `plot` syntax: It's much faster to compile, and easier to read. To draw a line from the focus to a point on the ellipse, you can use the syntax [`(<angle>:<x radius> and <y radius>)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119444/tikz-drawing-a-line-to-the-edge-of-a-circle).

Note that for the empty circle, you can use a single `\filldraw` command, with colours specified separately for the `fill` and `draw`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate around = {-20:(0, 0)}]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1.5}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
      \draw (-3, 0) -- (3, 0);
      \filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] (-\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %empty focus
      \filldraw[black] (\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %focus
      \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=\a, y radius=\b];
      \draw [-latex] (\c,0) -- (30:{\a} and {\b});
      \draw [-latex] (\c,0) -- (130:{\a} and {\b});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks both answers are great but your is a lot simpler.

Comment: If you use the ellipse command, how would then draw the vectors to the ellipse edge?

Comment: Using  `\draw [-latex] (\c,0) -- ({\a * cos(30)},{\b * sin(30)});`, you'll get a line from the focus to a point 30 degrees along the ellipse.

Comment: @Jake Any specific reason why you did not use `(30:{\a} and \b)` or `(130:\a\space and \b)` (I know, not perfect with the needed spaces around `and` …)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Nope, just didn't think about it. Much neater!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{scope}[rotate around = {-20:(0, 0)}]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1.5}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
      \draw (-3, 0) -- (3, 0);
      \filldraw[white] (-\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %empty focus
      \draw (-\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %empty focus
      \filldraw[black] (\c, 0) circle (.05cm); %focus
      \draw[name path=ell1] plot[domain = -99:99] ({\a * cos(\x)}, {\b * sin(\x)});
      \draw[name path=ell2] plot[domain = -99:99] ({-\a * cos(\x)}, {\b * sin(\x)});
      \path[name path=line1] (\c, 0) -- (30:4cm);
      \path[name path=line2] (\c, 0) -- (150:4cm);
      \draw[->,name intersections={of=line1 and ell1,by={a}}] (\c,0) -- (a);
      \draw[->,name intersections={of=line2 and ell2,by={b}}] (\c,0) -- (b);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your answer is great but Jake's was a little bit easier.