# Tikz: drawing a line to the edge of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

If I wanted to draw a line to the edge of a circle, I could simple do the following

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
\draw (0, 0) circle (\a cm);
\draw[-latex] (0, 0) -- ({\a * cos(angle)}, {\a * sin(angle)});
```

where angle is what ever I specified.

So the problem I am facing is that I want to draw two sets of 3 lines.  One set will correspond to the smaller circles and the other to the larger circles.  The problem is the circles aren't define as above.  Additionally, I want to specify different angles for each line.

The code for the circles in question is

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,intersections}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle through extra radius/.code={% unorthodox addon for the through library
                                            % needs to be used after 'circle through'!
                                            % this can be avoided by slightly changing the source
  \tikz@addoption{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*(#1)}%
    \pgfset{/pgf/minimum width/.expanded=\pgf@tempa}%
  }%
}}
\tikzset{
  special style/.code={%
    \if#1\tikz@nonactiveexlmark
      \pgfkeysalso{@special style}%
    \else
      \pgfkeysalso{style/.expanded=#1}%
    \fi
  },
  @special style/.style={draw=none,fill=none}
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .7,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {fill, outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = none, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
  ]
    \begin{scope}[rotate around ={-23.9625:(.75, -1)}]
      \begin{scope}
        \clip(-1, -4) rectangle (.5, 4);
        \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red, thick]
        plot ({0.8 * (-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
        {1.83 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
      \end{scope}
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {above, left = 3.5pt: \(P_2\)}] (P2) at
      (-1, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below, right = 5pt: \(F\)}] (F)
      at (.75, -1) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.7!(P2)$) coordinate (Fm) node[small dot =
      {below = 10pt, right = 3pt: \(F_m^*\)}] {};
      \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
        \foreach \dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in
        {.0cm, .4cm, .8cm}
          \node[draw, red,
          name path global/.expanded = \cPoint:\cRadius] at
          (P\cPoint.center) (\cPoint:\cRadius) [circle through = (Fm),
          circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius] {};
      \foreach \cRadius in {1, 2} {
        \tikzset{name intersections = {of/.expanded = {1:\cRadius} and
            2:\cRadius, name/.expanded = n'-\cRadius}}
        \foreach \cSolution in {1, 2}
          \node[black, scale = .5, big dot =
          {right, below = 5pt: $\ifnum\cSolution = 1\expandafter\tilde F\else       
            F\fi^*_\cRadius$}]
          (n-\cRadius-\cSolution) at (n'-\cRadius-\cSolution){};
        }
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So for the bigger circles, I want to draw lines in decreasing order from `70`, `35`, and `0` degrees from the `P1`, and for the smaller circles, `-225`, `-180`, and `-145` degrees again in increasing line length order.

Comment: @dustin The `\tikzset` with the definition of the `special style` is not needed anymore. This was only in it to simply hide a circle with the option `!` (which should have been done better and should have been better explained, I apologize). The circles are in fact nodes with the names `1:0`, `1:1`, `1:2` and `2:0`, `2:1` and `2:2`. You can use `{1:0}.<some angle>` to access a point on the circle. Example: `\draw ({1:2}.70) -- ({1:1}.35) -- ({1:0}.0);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I understand now.  If you want to make your comment and answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @dustin Are the big ones (the `1` comes from the center dot: `P1`). By the way, while `({\a * cos(angle)}, {\a * sin(angle)})` is mathematical correct, TikZ offers a much simpler input: `(angle:\a)`, the polar coordinate syntax. This also explains why the node names in my example above need to be enclosed in braces. I’ll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is going to be a very long answer (both in length and detailedness).
Keep calm and keep reading. :)

### How to access a coordinate on a circle/an ellipse: polar coordinates

While you can access a coordinate on a circle (or an ellipse with different radii) by using

```
({<x radius> * cos(<angle>)}, {<y radius> * sin(<angle>)})
```

TikZ offers a much simpler input with *polar  coordinates*. Its implicit form is:

- `(<angle>:<radius>)` for a coordinate on a circle and
- `(<angle>:<x radius> and <y radius>)` for a coordinate on an ellipse.

### How to access a coordinate on a circle/an ellipse which center does not lie in the origin: shifting/`calc`ulations

Of course, in this way, we can only access coordinates on circles/ellipses which center is located in the origin. The `shift` key comes in handy when you want to access other polar coordinates. The sequences (the first without, the second with the `calc` library)

```
\draw[shift=(P1)] (120:1cm) -- (50:.5cm) -- (40:.2cm);
\draw ($(P1)+(120:1cm)$) -- ($(P1)+(50:.5cm)$) -- ($(P1)+(40:.2cm)$);
```

would connect coordinates that lie on circles around `(P1)`.

### How to access a polar coordinate on a (circular) node: the endless possibilities of nodes

But do we actually know the exact radii? No, we also have never specified them at all.
The `through` library makes it possible to draw circles through points without specifying a radius. We could certainly use the `calc` library and its `let … in …` path operator to calculate it, but we don’t need to.

Besides (compass) anchors like `north` and `south east` every shape also includes (or should include) a definition for its border.
To make a long story short (it’s rather different for other shapes that are not `circle` or `ellipse`): All coordinate on a circular node are easily accessible:

```
(<node name>.<angle>)
```

The created circles in our examples are `circle` nodes named:

- for circles around `(P1)`

  - `1:0` (extra radius = `.0cm`)
  - `1:1` (extra radius = `.4cm`)
  - `1:2` (extra radius = `.8cm`)
- for circles around `(P2)`

  - `2:0` (extra radius = `.0cm`)
  - `2:1` (extra radius = `.4cm`)
  - `2:2` (extra radius = `.8cm`)

<sub>(There is something else to consider when connection nodes in this or any other way: The default value of `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` is set to `.5\pgflinewidth` which means that the accessed anchors/angles lie on the outside of the border of the path (a line has a width!). This does not apply here since `circle through` also sets both outer separators to zero making it more like the typical `circle`/`ellipse` path operators.)</sub>

#### Note to myself: Think ahead! `;)`

But why does

```
\draw (1:2.70) -- (1:1.35) -- (1:0.0);
```

give such faulty output?

Well, when TikZ parses coordinates it checks for various text sequences that implicit certain coordinates.

After checking for coordinate systems (`cs:`), intersections (`intersections`), coordinates perpendicular and horizontal to other coordinates (`|-` and `-|`), it checks first for polar (`:`), then for Cartesian coordinates (`,`). If none of these apply, only now the coordinate is interpreted as a node specifcation. (So the coordinates above are interpreted as polar coordinates with angles `1` and radii of `2.7,`1.35`and`0.0`.)

We can solve this by:

- protecting the `:` from the parser:

  ```
  \draw ({1:2}.70) -- ({1:1}.35) -- ({1:0}.0);
  ```
- using the explicit form of the node coordinates:

  ```
  \draw (node cs: name=1:2,  angle=70) --
        (node cs: name=1:1, anchor=35) --
        (node cs: name=1:0, anchor=east);
  ```

  The options `angle` and `anchor` interchangeable.
- *not using `:` in the first place* (recommended).
  Naming the nodes from `1-0` through `2-2` makes it easier to use the implicit form:

  ```
  \draw (1-2.70) -- (1-1.35) -- (1-0.0);
  \draw (2-2.-225) -- (2-1.-180) -- (2-0.-145);
  ```

  I hope, I have understood you correctly regarding what points you want to connect. Or are you looking for the following?

  ```
  \path (P1) edge (1-2.70) edge (1-1.35) edge (1-0.0)
        (P2) edge (2-2.-225) edge (2-1.-180) edge (2-0.-145);
  ```

  ---

  Note: I have used `:` in the previous answer to have the same names for the nodes as for their paths. Using `-` in the path names has failed in some stage of answering, `:` worked somehow. Now, it works again with `-`. Color me puzzled.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,intersections}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle through extra radius/.code={% unorthodox addon for the through library
                                            % needs to be used after 'circle through'!
                                            % this can be avoided by slightly changing the source
  \tikz@addoption{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*(#1)}%
    \pgfset{/pgf/minimum width/.expanded=\pgf@tempa}%
  }%
}}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .7,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {fill, outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = none, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
  ]
    \begin{scope}[rotate around ={-23.9625:(.75, -1)}]
      \begin{scope}
        \clip(-1, -4) rectangle (.5, 4);
        \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red, thick]
        plot ({0.8 * (-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
        {1.83 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
      \end{scope}
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {above, left = 3.5pt: \(P_2\)}] (P2) at
      (-1, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below, right = 5pt: \(F\)}] (F)
      at (.75, -1) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.7!(P2)$) coordinate (Fm) node[small dot =
      {below = 10pt, right = 3pt: \(F_m^*\)}] {};
      \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
        \foreach \dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in
        {.0cm, .4cm, .8cm}
          \node[draw, red,
          name path global/.expanded = \cPoint-\cRadius] at
          (P\cPoint.center) (\cPoint-\cRadius) [circle through = (Fm),
          circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius] {};
      \foreach \cRadius in {1, 2} {
        \tikzset{name intersections = {of/.expanded = {1-\cRadius} and
            2-\cRadius, name/.expanded = n'-\cRadius}}
        \foreach \cSolution in {1, 2}
          \node[black, scale = .5, big dot =
          {right, below = 5pt: $\ifnum\cSolution = 1\relax\tilde F\else       
            F\fi^*_\cRadius$}]
          (n-\cRadius-\cSolution) at (n'-\cRadius-\cSolution){};
        }
    \end{scope}

    \draw (1-2.70) -- (1-1.35) -- (1-0.0);
    \draw (2-2.-225) -- (2-1.-180) -- (2-0.-145);
    % or
    \path (P1) edge (1-2.70) edge (1-1.35) edge (1-0.0)
          (P2) edge (2-2.-225) edge (2-1.-180) edge (2-0.-145);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Connecting coordinates on the circles

[image]

#### Connecting coordinates on the circle with the center point

[image]

Comment: From your first comment, I knew what I needed to do.  You don't have the lines I was looking to create but I was able to create it from that comment.  If you want to see the code or what the intent was, just ask.

Comment: @dustin That’s okay. I have updated my answer with an image of the other idea how I understood your request. Maybe that’s it. Or not. At least I could help you. `:)`

Comment: That was the intent.