# Tikz: Drawing a line from a focus to the edge of an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

This question is similar to [Tikz: connecting two vectors from the focus of an ellipse to the edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118029/tikz-connecting-two-vectors-from-the-focus-of-an-ellipse-to-the-edge) but not the same.

In this instance, I want the the length of line to be a specific distance.  If there was a circle center at the origin, my lines to the edge will only be in the 1st and 2nd quadrants.
I want to construct a line of unit length from F to the edge of the ellipse.  I don't know what angle would have this length though.
For the second line, I want it to be of length `1.524`.  These lengths are labelled `rone` and `rtwo` respectively.

One more caveat, the angle between `rone` and `rtwo` should be `107` degrees which is labelled `deltanu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.6789}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{1.524}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltanu}{107}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\am}{1.1442}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
    \node[scale = .75, fill, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[scale = .75, fill = none, big dot = {below: \(F^*\)}] (FS)
    at (-2 * \c cm, 0) {};
    \draw (-\c,0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
    \draw[red, thick] (0, 0) circle (1.523679cm);
    \draw[blue, thick] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My guess would be the intersection library but I don't know how that would be implemented.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please state where the lines should start or better what to draw? To be honest the question is in the form of a math problem which is not helping for the TikZ problem.

Comment: @dustin `\path` two circles from F with 1 and 1.54 radius and use intersections with the ellipse. It's the straightforward examples from the manual. If your computation is right the angle should come out correct.

Comment: @Jake I added the information from the book.  See OP

Comment: @Jake I changed the code to show the orbits of Mars and Earth with the ellipse centered at `(-\c, 0)` to put the focus in relation to the sun being the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [correct value of *e* = 0.2678](http://prussing.ae.illinois.edu/Errata.1ed.pdf), you can use the `intersections` library to find the points P1 and P2:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.68}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{1.524}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltanu}{107}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\am}{1.14}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
    \node[scale = .75, fill, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[scale = .75, fill = none, big dot = {below: \(F^*\)}] (FS)
    at (-2 * \c cm, 0) {};
    \draw [name path=ellipse] (-\c,0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
    \draw [red, thick, name path=r2] (0, 0) circle (1.523679cm);
    \draw [blue, thick, name path=r1] (0, 0) circle (1cm);

    \draw [name intersections={of=ellipse and r1}] (F) -- (intersection-1) coordinate (P1) node [fill,big dot=right:P1, minimum size=3pt] {};
    \draw [name intersections={of=ellipse and r2}] (F) -- (intersection-1) coordinate (P2) node [fill,big dot=above left:P2, minimum size=3pt] {};

    \draw let
            \p0=(F),
            \p1=(P1),
            \p2=(P2),
            \n1={atan2(\x1-\x0,\y1-\y0)},
            \n2={atan2(\x2-\x0,\y2-\y0)},
            \n3={1em}
        in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc [radius=\n3, start angle=\n1, end angle=\n2] node [pos=0.5,above] {\pgfmathparse{\n2-\n1}%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^\circ$
        };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we determine the angle and distance to ensure they match the values given?

Comment: It is good to know that they don't fix their errors in the newer editions.  I have ed 2 and that errata is for ed 1.

Comment: @dustin: I've edited my answer to show how to calculate and print the angle.

Comment: @dustin: No, sorry. That could be a good question for Math.sx, though.

Comment: I think it may be easier than what we think.  `\draw (\ctilde, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \btilde cm);` so that will plot the other ellipse.  The thing I would need to find is the rotation that would bring it to correct location.  Then I just need to through in a scope for the rotate around.  Any ideas on how to find the rotation angle?